# How to have different react components share and acknowledge each other's states?

Tags: reactjs

I've frequently encountering dynamic components not being able to update each other directly. Multiple models that update each other's attributes but not their views.

```
model2View.onClick=() {
  model1.change;
  model1View.forceUpdate();
}
```

i've often resorted to throwing in callback functions into the mix which is just a wrapper that updates the model and forceupdate the overhead view after change.

it gets worse when the model update is a modelside function that updates more than one model, in which case I've been using the nearest ancester view to perform the forceupdate.

```
model2View.onClick=() {
   the following 3 could be wrapped in one method on model1
  model1.change;
  model2.change;
  model3.change;

  modelsWrapperView.forceUpdate();
}
```

After many force updates, I am just wondering if that's the way react was meant to be used or I'm missing something.

Here's an oversimplified example of the problem i'm trying to solve:

https://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/ann6qb30/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to mutate an object that is part of your state and React won't re-render because it doesn't know that something has changed. That's why you're having to call `forceUpdate`.

You should treat state as immutable and use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) to update it ([updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ann6qb30/2/)):

```
class TransformersApp extends React.Component {
  toggleDeception() {

    // Create a new object rather than mutating the existing one.
    var newTransformer = Object.assign({}, this.state.transformer, {
      isDecepticon: !this.state.transformer.isDecepticon
    });

    // Update the state.
    this.setState({
      transformer: newTransformer
    });
  }
}
```

This is made clear by the docs for `setState`:

> *NEVER* mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

You may find it helpful to use something like [`Immutable.Map`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) as your state object as that will prevent you from mutating the state at all.

Comment: would this be a really big performance issue if I were to update hundreds of models bound to unrelated views? and this potentially loses the model identity from what i understand, setter and getter props will be taken out of commission. And would object's own attribute modifier from this point build a clone object? From my pov, this could be a more reactical-correct way of code, but forceUpdate is more performant, and keeps object integrity. Is there another way to do this without losing either of those?